# Order of execution in if statement

Tags: c, if-statement

I am looking at a piece of code which calls two functions func1(struct *ps) and func2(struct ps). func1() returns the results in struct pointed by ps which is then used to call func2(). This is how the code looks,

```
if(func1(&ps) && func2(ps)) 
{
<<do something>>
}
```

This is C code. I am pretty sure that the order in which func1() and func2() are called is compiler dependent. But, still need an expert opinion. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, `func1` will always be evaluated first, and `func2` will only be evaluated if `func1` is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order here is defined as `func1(&ps)` executes before `func2(ps)`.  The `&&` operator has a property known as short circuiting.  If the left side executes to 0 then the right side will never execute.  Hence you are guaranteed that `func1(&ps)` executes before `func2(ps)`